# Spring MVC - simple file upload HTTP Status 500 - Could not parse multipart servlet request

Tags: java, file, maven, spring-mvc, upload

I'm starting learning the Spring MVC. Want to make web app with Excel file upload to database.

I'm starting with simple file upload and got problems at beginning.

My project made in Netbans using Maven and Tomcat 8.

I made simple example project with tutorial

https://saarapakarinen.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/building-a-basic-spring-3-web-project-netbeans-and-maven/

and it worked perfectly, but I wanted to change it a little to file upload based on official Spring help

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

I got opening form with file upload, when I select file and submit it i got an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

How to solve this and where is error? It is error in my code or I'm missing somthing, or got wrong configuration?

I have one form on form.jsp file and one controller class HelloController why its not working?

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <!-- name of the project//-->
        <display-name>HelloProject</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>


        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/application/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- max time of the session //-->

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <!-- default page //-->
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>application/form.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

**front-controller-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!-- configuration to fetch jsp files automatically from WEB-INF/jsp -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>



</bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="helloweb"/>



</beans>
```

**form.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>Form Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
              <label>file to send: <input type="file" name="file" /></label>
              <input type="submit" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloweb;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


@Controller
public class HelloController 
{

    private String startmessage="start";

    @RequestMapping("form")
    public String viewLoginPage(Model model)
    {  
          model.addAttribute("message", startmessage);
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(
            @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file) 
    {


    if((file.isEmpty()) )
    {
        startmessage="file empty";
        return "redirect:form";        
    }
    else
    {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    return "hello";
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: springMultipartFilter would not be required. Try removing this and build again. This filter is an alternative to using DispatcherServlet's MultipartResolver support and you are already using DispatcherServlet's MultipartResolver support.

Comment: I added this filter to try solve the problem, somewhere this was suggestion to solve similar problem. Thanks, I removed the filter and now I get redirect to hello.jsp page. Updated web.xml here without filter.

Comment: Do I need a viewLoginPage() method? It's not neccesary to do in my project, because I wanna get a uploaded file from form and use login() method do store the file, not any other method in the controller. But when I remove the viewLoginPage() method, I got error `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported`

Comment: First you would need to supply controller name into action="<controller>" field of jsp. Second you don't need get method then don;t provide one, you would need to submit the form to url. If you type a url in address bar of a browser and hit enter, it's always a GET request, so you had to specify POST request.

Comment: I'm using only POST, in controller and jsp. My goal is actually import XLS files to PostgreSQL database using Apache POI and Hibernate and then present it on site. Am I'm even goin now in good direction or should find better method of uploading XLS files?